# Bandwidth Limit for IIS FTP 7.0(or 7.5)

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, ftp, bandwidth-control

FTP Server 7 doesn't support to set bandwidth limit on upload or download. Is there any way to limit bandwidth of both upload or download? Is there any extension or plugin to have this feature. I don't want to use third party ftp servers. Maybe, there is an extension for IIS to limit.

Edit: I want to limit per user or virtual directory.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can only impose a download bandwidth limit if the ftp site is part of a website.

In the right hand Actions pane (IIS Manager), in the subsection "Configuration" press "Limits...".